# WPF Datagrid Scrollbar Inconsistent

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a Windows Forms application which needs a data grid with a wide vertical scroll bar. I built a WPF User Control containing a DataGrid with a scrollbar; I also built a simple Windows Forms test form with a single ElementHost element to host the user control.

The test form works exactly as desired, showing a wide vertical scroll bar. However, when I do the exact same thing in my existing WinForms app (I added an ElementHost with the user control as the child), the scrollbar is nowhere to be found (even though the data extends far below the size of the ElementHost).

It seems like the behavior should be identical between the test form and my application - how can I debug this when the behavior is different with no code difference?

```
<UserControl x:Class="OrdersGrid.OrdersGrid"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:app="clr-namespace:OrdersGrid"
         mc:Ignorable="d" Width="1014" Height="494"
         >
<UserControl.Resources>
    <app:StatusToBackgroundConverter x:Key="StatusToBackgroundConverter"/>

</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="494">        
    <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="492" Width="1012" x:Name="ordersGrid"
              SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataContext="orders" EnableRowVirtualization="True"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="50"/>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </Style>                 
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCellsPresenter">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
            </Style>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static DataGrid.FocusBorderBrushKey}" Color="#FF000000"/>               
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=Item.Status,Converter={StaticResource StatusToBackgroundConverter}}"/>

            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>                
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="orderId" Width="35" Binding="{Binding Num}" Header="" SortMemberPath="Num"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="shipDate" Width="90" Binding="{Binding ShipDate}" Header="Ship Date" SortMemberPath="ShipDate"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Shipper" Width="55" Binding="{Binding Shipper}" Header="Via" SortMemberPath="Shipper"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ArrivDate" Width="95" Binding="{Binding ArrivDate}" Header="Must Arrive"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="CustomerName" Width="120" Binding="{Binding customerName}" Header="Customer"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="AddressCode" Width="95" Binding="{Binding PRSTADCD}" Header="ADCD"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="CityState" Width="125" Binding="{Binding CityState}" Header="City State"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="OrderNum" Width="105" Binding="{Binding OrderNum}" Header="Order Num"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="CasesEaches" Width="95" Header="Order" Binding="{Binding BinCasesEaches}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="CustPONum" Width="95" Binding="{Binding CustPONum}" Header="Cust PO" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Status" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Status}" Header="Status" Visibility="Visible" SortMemberPath="Status"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="SortKey" Width="95" Binding="{Binding SortKey}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="PickedBy" Width="95" Binding="{Binding PickedBy}"  Visibility="Hidden"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ClosedBy" Width="95" Binding="{Binding ClosedBy}"  Visibility="Hidden"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ClosedShortBy" Width="95" Binding="{Binding ClosedShortBy}"  Visibility="Hidden"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you share the xaml of your user control?

Comment: You're talking about a Windows Form application with WPF controls. Like @PiyushParashar said, please provide the XAML, and edit your question so it's more readable and not confusing.

Comment: Edited my post to include the XAML for the UserControl...

Comment: I may have solved my own problem - the ElementHost width was getting set in the code-behind so there was not enough width to show the wide scrollbar - once I took care of the width constraint, the vertical scrollbar now seems to appear consistently.